# google cloud SDK can not download that generate this error

Tags: installation, google-cloud-sdk

google cloud SDK cannot download that generates this error.

'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advance System Settings and add environment variable path as C:\Windows\System32 just like you edit environment variable path after installing JDK. Hope it works...